# Spring Boot versions compatibility with Vaadin framework versions

Tags: spring, spring-boot, vaadin

We are currently using the following frameworks and its versions.

Spring Boot parent - 1.4.5.RELEASE
Vaadin-Bom - 7.7.3
Vaadin Spring Boot Starter - 1.1.0
Vaadin-Spring - 1.1.0

Planning to upgrade the spring boot parent version. But i'm sure if we upgrade the spring boot parent version, then need to upgrade the Vaadin dependencies. 
I spent few days to find the latest Vaadin frameworks compatibility with the 
Spring Boot jars. But couldn't able to arrive at solution. Could you please share your suggestions.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

Since [Vaadin 7 end-of-life](https://vaadin.com/blog/what-does-vaadin-7-end-of-life-mean-for-your-app-) happened already I would suggest migrating to Vaadin 8. You can check the versions in [Vaadin 8 full stack app starter with Spring](https://vaadin.com/start/framework/full-stack-spring)